# How do I manually set input values in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using [react-bootstrap-validation](https://github.com/heilhead/react-bootstrap-validation) to validate input fields. I want the option of setting some input fields based on a click. I know I need to set the state instead of the DOM directly, but not sure how in this case.

Specifically I want to set fields on [this line in the onClick handler](https://github.com/magician11/digisign/blob/master/src/js/components/notary-form.jsx#L37) where I'm using `console.log` instead.

The relevant code:

```
generateKeys() {
  console.log('generating keys...');
  let keyPair = tweetnacl.sign.keyPair();
  let publicKey = tweetnacl.util.encodeBase64(keyPair.publicKey);
  let secretKey = tweetnacl.util.encodeBase64(keyPair.secretKey);
  let encryptedSecretKey = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secretKey, 'superfreak').toString();
  console.log(publicKey);
  console.log(secretKey);
  console.log(encryptedSecretKey);
}

render() {
...
  <p>Don't have your own keys? Generate a once-off pair by clicking <a href="#" onClick={this.generateKeys} >here</a>.</p>
  <ValidatedInput
    type='text'
    label='Your public key'
    name='publicKey'
    validate='required'
    errorHelp='Please paste in your public key here'
  />
...
```

Thoughts on best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try always to add the relevant code. It will increase the chance someone helps you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValidatedInput` seems to extend from `Input` so you could use the `value` property of this component to set the value.

You could try something like this in your `generateKeys` method:

```
generateKeys() {
  ...
  this.setState({publicKeyValue: publicKey});
  ...
}
```

And then use the `publicKeyValue` state to set the value:

```
<ValidatedInput
  type='text'
  label='Your public key'
  name='publicKey'
  validate='required'
  errorHelp='Please paste in your public key here'
  value={this.state.publicKeyValue}
/>
```

Comment: perfect! So simple. Thank you.